# Business Objects BI Platform 4.1SP2 installation failure -- java VM installer

Tags: business-objects

I am stuck at the moment and need some help advise. I am trying to install the software above on a windows 8 machine for the company I work for. Initially I installed it but when I tried to do the wdeploy predeployall I got an error with acess denied to sAPJVM, it didn't actually exist in  the win64_X64 folder. After reading abit, I decided to uninstall and re-install. Howver the re-install failed with the following error

java virtual machine launcher
could not find main class: com/businessobjects/sdk/biar/utility/xsdutility. program will exit

Now I can't uninstall or install so stuck in abit of a limbo. I also notice that the SAPJVM is not there either.

Can anyone offer advise on how I get over this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if your using a tomcat server and the server is on another box, you need to run cmd as the administrator. This was my issue.